# ANOVA-like analysis of more complicated covariance-based metrics

Tags: anova, covariance, effective-rank

There is a set of variables that is observed over multiple trials and conditions. In order to explore signal changes across variables and across conditions, one typically uses ANOVA/MANOVA. However, frequently, the target of the study are not the changes in the signal itself, but changes in some derived quantity describing the behaviour of the whole set of variables. For example, one commonly used metric is effective rank (eRank). It estimates the dimensionality of the system by counting the number of principal components above a certain threshold. For example, if we have 50 variables, we could compute eRank for some given condition. If that eRank evaluates to e.g. 20, we could (very loosely speaking) conclude that only 20 of those 50 variables are independent, and the rest are linear combinations of the former to a good approximation.

The question is: how to evaluate which conditions have most effect on a metric like eRank. For example, we have different individuals and different treatments.

The naive approach would be to evaluate the metric for each condition combination separately, and then compare the resulting numbers. But this does not work. For example, let's say we evaluate eRank separately for treatment A and treatment B. Let's imagine the situation where all variables have the same strong reaction to treatment, but also have a variable-specific random component. Then, eRank would be high if evaluated separately for each treatment, but low if evaluated for concatenation of both conditions, since then there will be one strong principal component due to reaction to treatment.

Hence, I am looking for an ANOVA-like protocol for an arbitrary covariance-based metric. I imagine it would approximately work as follows:

1. Evaluate the metric for each combination of conditions and each combination of concatenations of conditions
2. Use results to estimate the marginal effect of each condition on the metric value

Note: eRank is not the only metric of this kind that is frequently used in my field. For example, different functional connectivity estimators such as correlation, transfer entropy and partial information decomposition are frequently used. Thus, I require a protocol that treats the metric as a black box estimator that can be applied to different partitions of the data.